# How to get 3 monitors working in Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, monitors, amd-graphics, amd

I have an Asus laptop with and AMD C-60 APU and Radeon HD Graphics and an AMD Radeon HD 6290 and 2gb of RAM (I know, pretty bad, but I'm not gonna be hacking into the mainframe of the Pentagon). I've got 3 monitors set up, but can't get them to work. I can only get 2 at a time. Is this a problem with my PC, or have I not configured it correctly?

Comment: I have the same question. 3 monitors worked out of the box on Ubuntu provided you don't use nvidia drivers. But since switching to Mint, it only shows the mint logo. Hoping for an answer as well.

Comment: i am running linux mint 18 with 3 monitors without problems, 1st Monitor is laptop itself, 2nd monitor is a acer via hdmi which is also set as main desktop, 3rd monitor is also a acer via VGA

Comment: @roman204 Right, I think this is a problem of laptops that do not have VGA output. This driver is needed if you put your laptop on a docking station.